# Converting C# method to quote SQL identifiers to F#

Tags: c#, f#

I'm porting the following method (QuoteIdentifier) from C# to F#. It quotes SQL identifiers (also handling embedded and incorrect quotes).

For example: QuoteIdentifier("dbo.mytable", "[", "]") outputs "[dbo].[mytable]"

Unfortunately, the F# code is even less readable than the C#. Is there a better way to write this in F#?

C# original:

```
public static string QuoteIdentifier(string id, string quotePrefix, string quoteSuffix) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        return id;
    return String.Join(".", SplitIdentifier(id, quotePrefix, quoteSuffix));
}

private static string[] SplitIdentifier(string id, string quotePrefix, string quoteSuffix) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        return new string[] { id };
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    int index = 0;
    do {
        list.Add(GetNextIdentifier(id, quotePrefix, quoteSuffix, ref index));
    } while (index != id.Length);
    return list.ToArray();
}

private static string GetNextIdentifier(string id, string quotePrefix, string quoteSuffix, ref int startIndex) {
    int index = startIndex;
    bool quoted = false;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(quotePrefix)) {
        builder.Append(quotePrefix);
        quoted = (String.CompareOrdinal(id, startIndex, quotePrefix, 0, quotePrefix.Length) == 0);
        if (quoted)
            index += quotePrefix.Length;
    }
    for (int i = index; i < id.Length; i++) {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(quoteSuffix) && String.CompareOrdinal(id, i, quoteSuffix, 0, quoteSuffix.Length) == 0) {
            if ((i + quoteSuffix.Length) == id.Length) {
                index = id.Length;
                break;
            }
            if (id[i + quoteSuffix.Length] == '.') {
                index = (i + quoteSuffix.Length + 1);
                break;
            }
            builder.Append(quoteSuffix).Append(quoteSuffix);
            if (String.CompareOrdinal(id, (i + quoteSuffix.Length), quoteSuffix, 0, quoteSuffix.Length) == 0)
                i++;
        } else {
            index = (i + 1);
            if (!quoted && id[i] == '.')
                break;
            builder.Append(id[i]);
        }
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(quoteSuffix))
        builder.Append(quoteSuffix);
    startIndex = index;
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

F# rewrite:

```
[<CompiledName("QuoteIdentifier")>]
let quoteIdentifier id quotePrefix quoteSuffix = 
    let isEmpty = String.IsNullOrEmpty
    let notEmpty = not << isEmpty
    let prefix, suffix = quotePrefix, quoteSuffix
    let equal strA indexA strB = (String.CompareOrdinal(strA, indexA, strB, 0, strB.Length) = 0)
    let getNext start =
        let builder = new StringBuilder()
        let append (s:string) = builder.Append(s) |> ignore
        let quoted = 
            if notEmpty prefix then
                append prefix
                equal id start prefix
            else false
        let index = if quoted then start + prefix.Length else start
        let rec loop i n =
            if i = id.Length then (i, n)
            else
                if notEmpty suffix && equal id i suffix then
                    if (i + suffix.Length) = id.Length then (i, id.Length)
                    elif id.[i + suffix.Length] = '.' then (i, i + suffix.Length + 1)
                    else
                        append suffix
                        append suffix
                        loop (if (equal id (i + suffix.Length) suffix) then i + 2 else i + 1) n
                else
                    if not quoted && id.[i] = '.' then (i, i + 1)
                    else
                        append (id.[i].ToString())
                        loop (i + 1) (i + 1)
        let _, next = loop index index
        if notEmpty suffix then append suffix
        (builder.ToString(), next)
    let split() = 
        0 
        |> Seq.unfold (function 
            | i when i = id.Length -> None 
            | i -> Some (getNext i)) 
        |> Seq.toArray
    if isEmpty id then id
    else String.Join(".", split())
```

Comment: I'm looking for a general approach, not necessarily a complete rewrite (although rewrites are welcome). I'm still unclear on the best way to translate imperative loops when the iterator variable may be modified in the body of the loop (eg, for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { if ((i % 7) = 0) i++; }).

Comment: why not use a while loop instead of a for loop in that scenario?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I realize I omitted the other thing that makes a loop difficult to translate in my view: early exits. But you're right, if mutating the iterator variable was the only obstacle a while loop would suffice. In some cases I've had luck using Seq.unfold to overcome both of these two obstacles: (1) mutating the iterator variable, and (2) early exits.

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest a simpler version of the C# code? I can't test it right now, but something like this should work:

```
public static string QuoteIdentifier(string id, string quotePrefix, string quoteSuffix) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id)) {
        return id;
    }
    var identifiers = id.Split(new char[] {'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var separator = string.Format("{0}.{1}", quoteSuffix, quotePrefix);
    var quotedString = string.Join(separator, identifiers);
    return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", quotePrefix, quotedString, quoteSuffix);
}
```

Once you have this working, you can convert it to a also short F# version.

Comment: i believe the "var identifiers..." line is wrong.  When calling "id.Split()", you don't need "id" as the first parameter.

Comment: The method does a bit more than this. It handles embedded quote characters as well.  Perhaps it should have been named FixQuotes or NormalizeQuotes.  I wrote the C# version several years ago and it has been working perfectly well (AFAIK) in production since.

Comment: Very true and code corrected, thanks. That's the problem when writing code on the fly

Comment: -1 This version does a tiny subset of the one in the original post.

Comment: Just for curiosity, how come that you decided to downvote me after nine days?

Comment: SO asked me to mark a response as an answer. That prompted me to look at the post for the first time in a while.

Comment: @Konamiman - I appreciate your response, but since I'm relatively new to F#, I was really looking for someone to suggest a more functional solution, not redefine the problem.

Comment: It's fine, don't worry. I just found strange that you didn't downvote on the first place but did it after so many time.